# Get value from another file PHP

Tags: php

I'm using PHPMailer inside WordPress for sending mails. For this I have 3 files:

**contacts.php** - file with html form:

```
<?php 
/*
 * Template Name: Contacts
 */
 get_header(); ?>
<div class="container page">
    <h2>Напиши нам</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/mailer.php" method="post">
               <label for="fname">Имя*</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="first-name" required>
               <label for="tel">Телефон*</label>
               <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" required name="phone">
               <label for="tel">E-mail</label>
               <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
               <label for="">Сообщение*</label>
               <textarea required class="form-control" rows="8" name="msg"></textarea>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-contacts">Отправить</button>
            </form>
       </div>
         <div class="col-lg-7">

         </div>
      </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**mailer.php** - the handler for the form:

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST["first-name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["mail"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];

require_once("lib/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->FromName = "SomeName";
$mail->Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "username";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->AddAddress("someaddress@yandex.ru", "Name");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->SetFrom("someaddress@ya.ru", "OwnerName");

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $fname;


$body = file_get_contents("test.php");
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if($mail->Send())
    echo "Everything is okay";
else
    echo "Error!";

?>
```

**test.php** - html markup for letter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h5>First Name of Person:</h5>
        <?php
            echo $fname; //how can I get this variable value???
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have faced with a problem.
How can I get this? (see the third snippet and a comment inside). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest using herdoc syntax because file_get_contents does not automatically translate VARS unless you run eval() on it(I think). So, simply include('test.php'); which contains...

```
 $body = <<<EOD
 ....
    <h5>First Name of Person:</h5>
 $fname
 ....
 EOD;
```

Comment: The best way! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in session on your `POST` request and then display it. Also, in WP sessions are not enabled by default. You need to enable them like so.

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

- `$_SESSION['firstName'] = $_POST['first-name']; // Store`
- `<?php echo $_SESSION['firstName']; // Display ?>`

Comment: Thank you! But it does not work.
I added this line to mailer.php:
`$_SESSION['firstName'] = $_POST['first-name']; // Store`
And after that in test.php I try to use this:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h5>The first name of person:</h5>
        <?php
            echo $_SESSION['firstName'];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>`
And I receive empty line where echo is

Comment: Did you enable sessions with `session_start();`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do Heredoc syntax to define the html text along with variables. file_get_contents just read the text source of the file and store in your variable. You have to include this file wherever it needed and use heredoc syntax :

```
$body = <<<HTML

<h5>First Name of Person:</h5>
{$fname} 

HTML;
```

Of you can define your test.php with some template tags . Use some template variables and replace the value with the actual variable in your form processing code .
In test.php, use

```
<h5>First Name of Person:</h5>
{first_name}
```

Then after getting the contents using file_get_contents, replace template variables with the value received from POST .

```
$body = file_get_contents("test.php");
$body = str_replace("{first_name}",$fname,$body);
```

Do this for all values to be replaced .